# Weather Suggester - A simple program to suggest clothes depending on the weather condition and temperature

Tags: java, beginner

I have started learning Java last week and made this simple program to practice making conditional statements and using scanners. The program, as the name suggests, takes the input of a temperature and a weather condition to give you a suggestion for what type of clothes to wear and what equipment to carry (if needed). I would love for someone to review the code and suggest if there's anything I can write in a more optimal and readable way. My main purpose while learning is to get rid of bad habits before they become too bad.

```
import java.util.InputMismatchException;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class WeatherSuggestor {
    int temperature;
    String weatherCondition;
    
    public WeatherSuggestor(int temperatureParameter, String conditionParameter ) {
        temperature = temperatureParameter;
        weatherCondition = conditionParameter;
    }
    
    public void weatherClothes() {
        switch (weatherCondition) {
        case "R":
            System.out.println("Take your umbrella.");
            break;
        case "SU":
            System.out.println("Leave your umbrella.");
            break;
        case "SN":
            System.out.println("Take your scarf and gloves.");
            break;
        default:
            System.out.println("The input you gave for the weather was invalid.");
        }
    }
    
    public void temperatureClothes() {
        if (temperature < 10) {
            System.out.println("Wear heavy clothes.");
        } else if (temperature < 20) {
            System.out.println("Wear heavy clothes.");
        } else if (temperature < 30) {
            System.out.println("Wear long sleeve clothes.");
        } else {
            System.out.println("Wear light clothes.");
        }
    }
    
    @SuppressWarnings("resource")
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner temperatureInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner weatherInput = new Scanner(System.in);
        
        try {
            System.out.println("Enter today's temperature in Celsuis: ");
            int definedTemperature = temperatureInput.nextInt();
            
            System.out.println("(R) = Raining\n(SU) = Sunny\n(SN) = Snowy");
            System.out.println("Enter today's weather condition: ");
            String definedWeather = weatherInput.next().toUpperCase();
            
            WeatherSuggestor userOne = new WeatherSuggestor(definedTemperature, definedWeather);
            userOne.temperatureClothes();
            userOne.weatherClothes();
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            System.out.println("Invalid input.");
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: 19°C = Heavy clothes??  Long sleeves at 29°C???  No thanks!  I’ll stick to T-shirts & shorts … or perhaps a bathing suit.

Comment: @AJNeufeld Haha, I live in the Middle East where temperatures are like 45 C for 7 to 8 months. So, 10 C to 20 C is actually cold considering the temperature range :p (or maybe my body just can't handle cold temperatures).

Comment: I live in Canada where we get down to -40°C on extreme winter nights, and +40°C on extreme summer days.  25°C is comfortable beach weather.  I guess your “weather recommender” might need subclasses for regional recommendations :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## One Scanner Only

Do not create multiple scanners.  It is unnecessary, and may cause you grief later.  There is only one input stream (`System.in`) and having two scanner objects reading from it can produce unexpected results.

```java
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

    try {
        …
        int definedTemperature = scanner.nextInt();
        scannner.nextLine();  // Discard the newline after the integer
        …
        String definedWeather = scanner.next().toUpperCase();
        …
```

## Close Resources

Ensure you close resources.  Don’t just declare “ya, I know I’m leaking; Java will clean up for me eventually.”

The “try-with-resources” statement will allow you to automatically close resources, safely and easily.

```java
    try(Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in)) {
        …
        int definedTemperature = scanner.nextInt();
        …
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        …
    }
```

With the above, the `SuppressWarnings("resource")` is unnecessary.

## Redundant Condition

```java
        if (temperature < 10) {
            System.out.println("Wear heavy clothes.");
        } else if (temperature < 20) {
            System.out.println("Wear heavy clothes.");
```

The first and second condition behaviours are identical.  The first condition is entirely covered by the second condition, so you can combine these, eliminating the redundant test.

```java
        if (temperature < 20) {
            System.out.println("Wear heavy clothes.");
```

## Parameter names

```java
    public WeatherSuggestor(int temperatureParameter, String conditionParameter ) {
        temperature = temperatureParameter;
        weatherCondition = conditionParameter;
    }
```

`temperatureParameter` and `conditionParameter` are very verbose.  The “Parameter” aspect is entirely redundant, as it is clear they are method parameters.

You could simplify this using `this.` to distinguish between parameter names and object members, eliminating the need to come up with different “spellings”.

```java
    public WeatherSuggestor(int temperature, String weatherCondition ) {
        this.temperature = temperatureParameter;
        this.weatherCondition = weatherCondition;
    }
```

## Recommedations

### Input Validation

You have a dichotomy between invalid temperature input and invalid weather condition input.  The former causes an Exception to be thrown (and caught), where as the latter just prints an error message.

You can throw your own exceptions when the user gives invalid input.  This could be done after reading the input from the user, or could be done later in the constructor of `WeatherSuggestor`.  When `weatherClothes()` is called, the the `weatherCondition` member could be trusted to be valid.

### Study `enum`

You have 3 valid values for `weatherCondition`.  It is safer to use `enum` to encode these values.  Remembering whether the weather is two letter codes (`RA`, `SU`, `SN`) or a mixture of 1-letter and 2-letter codes (`R`, `SU`, `SN`) is error-prone.  As strings, the compiler can’t help you out, but an enumerated values, they are checked by the compiler and type-safe!

```java
enum WeatherCondition {
    RAINY, SUNNY, SNOWY;
}

…
         WeatherCondition condition;
         if (weatherCond == "R")
              condition = WeatherCondition.RAINY;
         else if …
```

### Return values

Instead of printing inside `weatherClothes()` and `temperatureClothes()`, you probably want to just return a String.  Leave the printing to the caller.